# How to understand "recursive" with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am working on a "recursive" project with BeautifulSoup in Python. I've read an official document and lots of questions but I still don't get it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = "<div>C<p><strong>A</strong>B</p></div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
```

1. `print(soup.find("p", recursive=False))` gives `None`

Is it because we can't find anything any more outside of `<div></div>`?

2. `print(soup.find("p").find(recursive=False))` gives `<strong>A</strong>`

If what I thought in the first question was correct,
I guessed this would give `<p>B</p>` because we can't go into a deeper depth. But why does this start from `<strong>`? why not `<p>`?

Also, how can I extract `<p>B</p>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML documents are nested, tags have tags inside of them.
In the document you've provided ('s'), the structure looks like:

```
Div
   p
     strong
        `text node A`
     `text node B`
```

Recursive is instructing beautifulsoup to check the children of a particular node for matches (or not to if set to false).

1. There is only one root node (div). Because you tell beautifulsoup NOT to check recursively, it will not look at the div's children, so it returns None since there are no root 'p' elements.
2. This is actually two instances of 'find' being chained together. The first 'find' looks for a 'p' (and looks recursively, since the default for recursive it True). It finds the 'div>p' as we'd expect. After this, you've called 'find' AGAIN on the result of the first find, which is then searching for anything since you didn't specify the node type you're looking for. The first child of the 'p' is the 'strong' tag, so that is what is returned.

Comment: Thank you ,I totally undrstood. but I'm in trouble now, can I ask one more thing?

Comment: I understood why print(soup.find("p").find(recursive=False)) gives <strong>A</strong>. but when I added "text=True" like -> print(soup.find("p").find(text=True, recursive=False)), it gives B. I don't understand why it doesn't give A which is inside the strong tag.

Comment: @Jihyun it's because the 'A' is nested inside of the <strong> tag, so to find it, you need to have recursive search enabled. Otherwise, the search will only find 'text' that is a direct descendant of <p>, which in this case is the 'B' textnode is

Comment: @Jihyun no worries. Please accept the answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: ohh I didn't know there was such a feature. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`Recursive = False` returns **only the children** of the element of the tag you are trying to find. For example:

```
<li>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
</li>

li = soup.find('li')
```

Now,

```
print(li.findChildren("p"))
```

> prints `[<p>1</p>, <p>2</p>, <p>3</p>]`

```
print(li.findChildren("p", recursive=False))
```

> prints `[<p>1</p>, <p>2</p>]`

In order to get `<p>B</p>` from `<div>C<p><strong>A</strong>B</p></div>`:

```
s = "<div>C<p><strong>A</strong>B</p></div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
soup.strong.decompose()
print(soup.p)
```

> prints `<p>B</p>`

Explanation:

```
print(soup.strong)
```

> prints `<strong>A</strong>`

```
soup.strong.decompose()
```

> removes `<strong>A</strong>` ([Beautiful Soup decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose))

```
print(soup.p)
```

> prints `<p>B</p>`

Comment: Perfect answer, I could follow it easily. Seems like all the other explanations I found were more complex than necessary!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `recursive=False`, it means to only search immediate children of the element that you're calling `.find()` or `.find_all()` on. The only immediate child of the top-level `soup` object is the `<div>` element. Since it's not a `<p>` element, it doesn't match the name given, so nothing is found.

In your second example, you first use a recursive search to find the `<p>` element. Then you call `.find()` with no name, so it will match any element name. Since you specified `recursive=false`, it only considers immediate children of `<p>`. The first child element is `<strong>A</strong>`, and that's returned.

Comment: Wow I really understood!!! Thank you! 